# JEE6: Get the Binding annotation in an interceptor implementation

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, interceptor

I have an interceptor binding, which is parameterized:

```
@InterceptorBinding
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Traced {

   @Nonbinding
   boolean traceFull() default true;
}
```

Then I define an interceptor implementation

```
@Interceptor
@Traced
public class TracingInterceptor implements Serializable { ... }
```

In the implementation I want to check which value is set to the traceFull-parameter.
(I do not want to implement three interceptor implementations for true, false and null)

So my implementation checks the Interceptor-Binding-Annotation of the intercepted method:

```
Traced traceAnnotation = context.getMethod().getAnnotation(Traced.class);
if (traceAnnotation != null && traceAnnotation.traceFull()) { ... }
```

This works fine but if I use a Stereotype or a nested interceptor binding then I don't get the @Traced annotatopn of the method and I cannot check the value which is set.

So my question is: How can I get the 'calling' binding within my interceptor implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible in CDI 1.0, but should be in CDI 1.1

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But is there any way to make an interceptor parameterizable with annotations? Maybe I have to write some code with Beanmanagers or something like that?

Comment: You might be able to get the annotation via java reflection from the innvocationcontext. IIRC, a lot of this is limited by the interceptor spec.

Comment: I'm using reflection to get it, using the getMethod() and getTarget() methods on invocation context. Problem is that WELD is returning the wrapped instance for getTarget() as opposed to the instance itself. Not too much a problem if my annotation is @Inherited, but a pain if it's not. Sadly I've not got it working for Stereotypes, so don't use them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection even for resolving the annotation from stereotypes.

Being in the same situation (requiring additional nonbinding information in the interceptor), I have implemented a utility method:

```
public <T extends Annotation> T findBindingAnnotation( Class<T> bindingType, InvocationContext ic )
{
    Method method = ic.getMethod();
    if ( method != null && method.isAnnotationPresent( bindingType ) )
    {
        return method.getAnnotation( bindingType );
    }
    Class<? extends Object> type = ic.getTarget().getClass();
    if ( type.isAnnotationPresent( bindingType ) )
    {
        return type.getAnnotation( bindingType );
    }

    T annotationFromStereoType = annotationFromStereoType( bindingType, type );
    if ( annotationFromStereoType != null )
    {
        return annotationFromStereoType;
    }

    throw new UnsupportedOperationException( "no binding annotation found: " + bindingType.getCanonicalName() );
}

private <T extends Annotation> T annotationFromStereoType( Class<T> bindingType, Class<? extends Object> type )
{
    for ( Annotation annotation : type.getAnnotations() )
    {
        Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType = annotation.annotationType();
        if ( annotationType.isAnnotationPresent( Stereotype.class ) )
        {
            if ( annotationType.isAnnotationPresent( bindingType ) )
            {
                return annotationType.getAnnotation( bindingType );
            }
            else
            {
                T recursiveLookup = annotationFromStereoType( bindingType, annotationType );
                if ( null != recursiveLookup )
                {
                    return recursiveLookup;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```